# How to pass a concatenated string argument to the system() function?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

How to pass a concatenated string argument to the `system()` function?

- I am using `GCC 4.5.2`
- I have to make a `std::string` get executed in `shell` and to write its output
  to an external file.
- I use the `system()` function in order to perform this task.

I couldn't perform the execution of this function since I could pass only `char*` arguments and no `std::string` arguments.

Here is my code..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void getch()
   {
   int c;
   fflush(stdout);
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c!= EOF) { /* Do Nothing */ }
   }

int main()
{
string optTechniques[] = {
        "-fauto-inc-dec", "-fcprop-registers", "-fdce",
        "-fdefer-pop", "-fdelayed-branch", "-fdse",
        ........,   .....,  ......
         }
string str;
str="gcc -Wall "+optTechniques[i]+" -o output";
cout<<"\n"<<str<<"\n";  /* Here it prints correctly */
system(str);    /* This is generating error. */
string val;
system("sh execTime.sh");

ifstream readFile("output.log");
readFile>>val;  /* Works perfectly if execution is done. */
float execTime=strtof(val.c_str(),NULL);    /* Converts the string to float */

getch();

cout<<"\nExecution Time: "<<execTime<<"\tTechnique: "<<optTechniques[i]<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

**Update:** *Thanks. I have got the answer.*

Comment: Did you write this code? Do you understand it? If so what is being done in this statement `strtof(val.c_str(),NULL);`? Specifically, `val.c_str()`? If you understand that You probably already know the answer?

Comment: Please post minimum code needed to compile and understand the problem. This is 1000 times better than posting unnecessary code. For eg. What's the necessity of a `getch` implementation in the code and a call to `getch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the char pointer from the string with `c_str`:.

```
system(str.c_str());
```